# Java recursion; how can I simplify what I have?

Tags: java, recursion

I have to write the following recursion method:

```
public static int countA(String s)
```

Yet I find it impossible to do this without declaring a counter and position variable; like so:

```
public static int countA(String s, int position) {

        int count = 0;

        if( s.charAt(position) == 'A' )
            count++;

        if( position + 1 < s.length() ) {
            count += countA(s, position + 1);
        }

        return count;
    }
```

How can I simplify my answer so that my method is the same as the one listed?

EDIT: Yes, I want to count all A's inside a string.

Comment: Please at least explain what the method is supposed to actually do.

Comment: I think OP wants to count "A"s inside the string

Comment: To count all A's in a String I wouldn't use recursion, simplify it using a loop going through the String.

Comment: @boskop: this is clearly not the point of this exercise. It probably is a requirement to use recursion in order to learn it.

Comment: It is quite strange to design a method like this to get that number. Recursion is more expensive than expected in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public static int countA(String s) {
    int count = 0;

    if (s == null)
        return 0;

    if (s.length() == 0)
        return 0;

    if (s.charAt(0) == 'A')
        count++;

    return count + countA(s.substring(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two forms of recursion,

- Tail Recursion : The return value is calculated as a combination of the value of current subroutine and the return value of the next call. Example,

  ```
  int factorial(int a) {
      if(a==0)
          return 1;
      else
          return a * factorial( a-1 );
  }
  ```
- Accumulator based recursion : You accumulate the results by adding an additional parameter and return the accumulated value.

  ```
  int factorial(int a, int fact) {
      if(a==0)
          return fact;
      else
          return factorial(a-1, a*fact);
  }
  ```

Obviously what you have here is accumulator based, while you can improve it to Tail recursion.

Tail recursion is considered more readable, **while it can cause a StackOverflow**! (no pun intended). This is because it has to push the current value to a stack, before calling subroutine again. And when you make a large number of such calls, this stack might go over its limit.

Some compilers optimize tail recursion to accumulator based in order to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
public static int countA(String s) {
        if(s==null) return 0;
        if(s.length()==0) return 0;
        if( s.charAt(0) == 'A' )
        {
            return 1 + countA(s.substring(1));
        } else 
        {
            return countA(s.substring(1));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should do the trick
Here we are assuming that countA returns the number of As inside String s

```
public static int countA(String s)
{
    if(s.length()==0) return 0;  // return 0 if string is empty
    else
    {
        // if the first char is A add 1 to the answer, recurse
        if(s.toCharArray()[0])=='A') return 1+countA(s.subString(1,s.length()));

        // else add nothing to the answer, recurse
        else return countA(s.subString(1,s.length()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You move the `position` variable out of the method and make it `static`(since your `countA()` is also `static`).

```
static int position = 0;
public static int countA(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    if( s.charAt(position) == 'A' )
        count++;
    if( position + 1 < s.length() ) {
        position++;
        count += countA(s);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you have the termination condition first, which then usually simplifies the code by reducing indentation/nesting and have a "do nothing" action for it (typically requiring one more iteration than absolutely required).

You also don't need the local variable!

```
public static int countA(String s, int position) {
    if (position == s.length())
        return 0;
    return (s.charAt(position) == 'A' ? 1 : 0) + countA(s, position + 1);
}
```